# Exclude maven sub modules dependencies from top level module

Tags: java, maven

I created a maven parent project with three modules :

- data-layer-module
- data-service-module (uses the data-layer-module)
- web-module (uses the data-services-module)

Here is a snippet from the parent pom.xml :

```
<groupId>org.mygroup</groupId>
<artifactId>myArtifact</artifactId>
<packaging>pom</packaging>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

<modules>
  <module>data-layer-module</module>
  <module>data-service-module</module>
  <module>web-module</module>
</modules>
```

The `data-layer-module` `pom.xml` contains no dependencies to the other modules (it contains only its external dependencies).

The `data-service-module` has a dependency in its `pom.xml` to the `data-layer-module` :

```
<dependencies>
      <dependency>
          <groupId>org.mygroup</groupId>
          <artifactId>data-layer-module</artifactId>
          <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
      </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

And the `web-module` has a dependency to the `data-service-module` :

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.mygroup</groupId>
    <artifactId>data-service-module</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</dependency>
```

Everything is fine but I don't want the `web-module` to have access to the `data-layer-module`. I need to enforce the three layer web-service-data model. Which is not the case with this configuration.
I obviously tried manually excluding it from the `web-module` `pom.xml` :

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.mygroup</groupId>
    <artifactId>data-service-layer</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.mygroup</groupId>
            <artifactId>data-layer-module</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

But this causes compilation error since the `data-service-module` can't find its `data-layer-module` dependency.

How could this configuration be done ?

Answer (score 1):

If the web module is going to run in the same jvm as the data-service-layer, then a transient dependency to the data-layer-module is necessary - this is why the exclusion you added casuses the application to fail.

You could consider making a simple api, for example data-service-layer-api, which obviously does not depend on data-layer-module, and is implemented correctly by data-service-layer.

You can still use a multi-module maven project, but now you will have 2 artifacts - a web module, and a data-service, which must be deployed separated.

It's basically a tradeoff between strict dependency analysis and project complexity.

Comment: Create a data-service-layer-api means add a new layer ? To summarize : The web-module communicates with the data-service-layer-api and the data-service-layer-api communicates with the data-service-module which in turn communicates withe the data-layer-module. Is that what you mean ? How this could prevent from transitive dependencies ?

Comment: No, it's like this: the web-module communicates via the api with the data-service-layer. It has no knowledge of the data-layer. The data-service-layer is running separately and knows about the data-layer.

Comment: I will try that. If you know any exemple on github please let me know.